# Выбрать 2 случайных файла из разных папок

Tags: php

Есть папки:

```
/p/b/coca   
/p/b/pepa   
/p/b/repa
```

В конечных папках содержатся картинки (`1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, ...), количество которых неизвестно.
Мне нужно выбрать `2` случайных картинки из разных папок, например так:

```
/p/b/coca/8.jpg    
/p/b/repa/1.jpg
```

и показать их на странице.
Названия конечных папок имеются в массиве с ключами.
Выбрать две случайных папки я могу при помощи `array_rand($brandName, 2);`
Что делать с файлами?
Прогонять все их через `readdir()` с записью в массив:

```
$files = [];
if ($handle = opendir($uploadDir))
{
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
    {
        if (! is_dir($uploadDir . '/' . $file))

            $files[] = $file;

    }
closedir($handle);
}
```

После выбирать из массива `array_rand($files)` — первая папка, `array_rand($files2)` — вторая папка.

Или есть более ухищренный способ проделать это?

Comment: Конечно есть, например `count()` и `scandir()`

Comment: @korytoff будет лучше rand(1, (count(scandir('/p/b/coca')) - 2))? ну как-то так получится ведь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
$files = []; // инициаоизация массива с файлами
foreach($brandName as $brand) { // проходим по массиву директорий
    $dirName = $uploadDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $brand;
    if(is_dir($dirName)) { // проверка на существование директории
        $filesTmp = scandir(); // получаем список файлов
        $files = array_merge($filesTmp, $files); // добавляем в общий список файлов
    }
}
$keys = array_rand($files, 2); // получаем 2 случайных ключа массива с файлами
foreach($keys as $key) {
    echo $files[$key], PHP_EOL; // работаем с нашими файлами
}
```

Писал логику, код не тестировал.